# helping with sprinkler conundrum

Tags: sprinkler-system

I would like some suggestions on how to solve this issue. My end goal is to add a zone for my garden area. Below is my rough drawing. I'm trying to avoid having to dig from my current manifold box to the garden area. The second picture is what I'm looking to do.

The red zone which is zone 4, I'm wondering If I can turn that into a water mainline take that red zone all the way to Box 2 and remove the T for 4 sprinklers in zone 4. Currently, there is no Box 2 but I can add one there. Then attach the previous zone 4 sprinklers into the new manifold? could that work?

Or I could take Zone 4 into box2 and add an additional manifold. Then I would have to turn on zone 4 in order for other zones in box 2 work. Could I do that?

My Controller has room for 8 zones and I can run the additional wires to box2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're after. Your red zone 4 looks like it goes right past the garden. Could the issue be solved by adjusting the spray heads to hit the garden instead of or in addition to the grass between them the next zone up? What is "box 2" (what's it going to be)? Are you looking to realign where the zone 4 piping goes? Maybe this makes more sense to someone with more background in sprinkler systems...

Comment: I do not understand why Zone 1 is overlayed/run in parallel with zone, 2,3 &4.in the back yard.  What is the purpose of Box 2.  Is Box 2 a future Manifold location?

Comment: I added the second picture. The second picture is what I'm looking to do. Basically I'm looking to remove T connection from zone 4 pipe and have that pipe goto box2 to provide water for additional zones. I don't want my current zone 4 to water my plants because I have raised beds and they require more water. I would run an additional zone from box 2 that will use a drip system and pressure reducer Ignore all other zones. Those are meant for demonstration purposes

Comment: What is the conundrum ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a fine idea to add another valve and manifold location and to convert that long section of red so that it's an always-on main line rather than just a zone 2 feeder.

Your desire to add a separate zone for the garden, rather than make the lawn zone water the garden too, is a good one for several reasons. For example, gardens and turf grass have different watering requirements; and broadcast watering over the garden wastes water and supports growth of weeds all over the garden.

When running wire to the new valve location remember that you need a conductor for every valve, plus one as a common, plus one or two spares for when "it would be nice if..." happens later. ;-)

Comment: When converting the Zone 4 line to a main, you can do this by manually leaving it on at the zone 4 valve.  the two new zones from box two would be controlled by zone 5 & 6 schedule timer.  Per Greg, run extra wires for expansion in the future.  Even the garden plants need different schedules.

Comment: Or check the controller - if there is a "master valve" option the old zone 4 valve can be opened by this and 5 and 6 on new connections.